# How can I find "UUID" in "gdb_items" ? In "gdb_items", "UUID" values are missing

Tags: sql, sqlite, arcgis-platform

I need to find "UUID" values in "gdb_items", can I find the values via relationship with other tables?

Note: I have other values in "gdb_items", all fields are fine except the "UUID" field. I just need "UUID" values.